# How can I find out the filenames of the files zipped and uploaded to Autodesk Forge Model Derivative backend?

Tags: autodesk-forge, cad, autodesk-model-derivative

So I am trying to upload a bunch of files to Autodesk using the model derivative API,
I am zipping them up, and passing in the rootFilename ( i.e an .sldasm file ) and a bunch of files in the same zip file ( i.e .sldprt files )

I want to be able to show the files that constitute the assembly ( i.e the sldprt files ) in a dropdown, but I seem to be getting a 'name' property from the Objects instead of the name of the actual file that was uploaded.

Is there a way to get the name of the files that were uploaded?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to get the filenames from? I'm a bit confused because since you're the one uploading the ZIP file, it should be pretty easy for you to find out the names of files inside the archive, right?

Comment: @PetrBroz , yeah I know the names of the files in the Archive, but what I'm trying to do is correlate the filenames to the Labels that show in the Model browser, so that if one were to select an appropriate filename from the assembly, it would open up the assembly but isolate out that component, which was added in by that file

Answer (score 0):

The Model Derivative service always tries to extract the most relevant hierarchy data depending on the input file format, and for Inventor files it's typically the logical structure of the assembly with the actual names of individual components. With that said, in case of Inventor files the service also extracts various properties for individual components that seem to correlate to the names of files they come from, like the `Rear Tilt Spring` example below:

[image]

But I'm not sure if this is a reliable way of establishing the connection between a component and a file (in other words, whether a component with `Component Name: Foo` will always come from a file called `Foo.ipt`).